# How to set some options in navigation drawer manually when using Navigation controller for others?

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am having 3 items in my navigation drawer menu as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/change_theme"
    android:icon="@drawable/change_icon"
    android:title="Change Theme" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/invite_friends"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
    android:title="Invite Friends" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/info_icon"
    android:title="About Us" />
</menu>
```

I want the about fragment item to use navigation controller to navigate to the about fragment and that is working fine but when I set functions to the other two as follows then it works for the item set here and the default navigation action for about us does not work.

```
private fun setUpNavigationDrawer() {
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navView.apply {
        setupWithNavController(navController)

        setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.change_theme -> someFunction()
                R.id.invite_friends -> someFunction()
            }
            true
        }
    }
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

how to set some options using the navigation controller and others manually?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `setupWithNavController()` you could set navigation easily as it explicated here :

```
/**
 * Sets up a [NavigationView] for use with a [NavController]. This will call
 * [android.view.MenuItem.onNavDestinationSelected] when a menu item is selected.
 *
 * The selected item in the NavigationView will automatically be updated when the destination
 * changes.
 */
```

So what you need to is that :

- In you nav_graph you need to put the fragment you need to navigate in a nested graph
- You need to give to this nested graph the exact same id you gave to the item menu
- So for example for `<item android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"` the id of the nested graph will be `aboutFragment`

You do not have to do nothing more to navigate from the drawer menu. Let us know if it is ok !

EDIT :

If you want to make a toast when clicking on menu items just do that :

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.nav_item_one -> Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    R.id.nav_item_two -> Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    R.id.nav_item_three -> Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item three", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    R.id.nav_item_four -> Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item four", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
return true
```

}

Good tutorial here : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-navigation-drawer-in-an-android-app--cms-30263

Good luck!

Comment: That works if I want to show a fragment but how to perform a function say a Toast on click on some drawer option. That's what I am asking

Comment: the problem is I want to do both that is I want toast for some options and for others I want fragment transactions using nav controller.

Comment: For those that you need toast do what I showed you in my edit answer. For navigation do the first thing I told you about nested graph and id

Comment: Yes, I did that but it is not using the navigation thing when I define toast for some of them. That is the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do many things on the same click :

```
when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.nav_item_one -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        otherActionYouWant()
    }
    R.id.nav_item_two -> Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked item two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```